# i want to call the controller before displaying the contents of a tab. Can anyone please advise how to accomplish this?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

i am New to spring. So pardon my knowledge regarding this.

I am working on an application, where there is a provision of displaying "History".
These contents of the "history" are calculated by calling the controller.
There is a "History" Tab as well.
The contents of the "history" tab will be blank, if the controller is not called.
AS a solution; 
I have implemented a button to call the controller. And once the controller is called, i access the "history" tab to display the details.

But i want to call the Controller when the "history" tab is clicked; and the contents of that tab be displayed accordingly.

Can anyone please suggest an idea about how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. All you have to do is an AJAX call when the history tab is clicked.
As part of your AJAX call, you controller on the server side is invoked and does some processing and return the history in the JSON format.

(I hope you are using JSON for communication)

You can define a Success call back method to process this JSON in the front end and you can display the history in the tab.

Comment: Can you please give a simple example as of how to return the history from the controller in the JSON format.                                              My method in the controller is mapped for "/data"                                  My jsp page is view.jsp ;  where there are 4 tabs. One of them History. I am using modelandview to return the control from the controller to the jsp page.

Comment: @AnkitDas depends on what you want to return as the History. What does History contain?

Comment: It want to return a model to the history. It will contain all my details.

Comment: You can add @ResponseBody annotation for the return type and Jackson mapper will automatically convert your Model object into JSON.

Comment: Just to add...                                                                               I have tried ajax to call the controller. From this controller i am rendering my model to view.jsp using modelandview().                                I want to know how to go to the history tab in the view.jsp.                     Please can you share an example.                                             It will be of great help.                                                           Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Its really confusing without the code. Share the code that explains what you have done so far.